# What is rack in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra-2.0, specifications

I am reading cassandra 2.0 manual the quotation (page 19, title NetworkTopologyStrategy, second paragraph):

*NetworkTopologyStrategy places replicas in the same data center by walking the ring clockwise until reaching the first node in another **rack**.*

What is meant by rack?

Answer (score 0):

It's a physical enclosure that houses several servers:

See e.g. this [wikipedia article.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/19-inch_rack)

One architecture is for each rack to house an ethernet switch, which interconnects all servers within one rack, meaning there can be a lot of available bandwidth between servers within one rack - topology knowledge which distributed systems can make use of to make the best out of available resources.

Read the [Understanding Hadoop Clusters and the Network](http://bradhedlund.com/2011/09/10/understanding-hadoop-clusters-and-the-network/) for more insigth.